# System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory,"") takes me to wrong path

Tags: c#, path, directory

I am loading this file which is located in a folder i created, the same folder is also rendered in the bin/debug folder, but i need to locate the file in the folder i created, the thing is the method which should find the path of the file by its name gives me the path of the debug folder instead of the on i created.

I have harcoded the path to show you the real location.

```
var path2 = System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "xulrunner");

var hardcodedPath= "C:\\Users\\Alan\\Desktop\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\xulrunner";
```

This is the result of path2 variable:

```
C:\\Users\\Alan\\Desktop\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\bin\\Debug\\xulrunner"
```

As you can see its pointing to different folder as hardcoded path.

Comment: But your `.exe` isn't under `bin\Debug` folder?

Comment: Correct, xulrunner file is present in bin/debug folder, but i need the method to return the path just as the hardcodedPath the xulRunner in the Debug folder is no good

Answer (score 2):

When running from Visual Studio, the working directory is different from your project location, usually it is two folders up (from `bin\Debug\`). In your distributed application, the working directory might be the same as that of other files you want to access since you copy some other files to the working directory.

I would recommend to keep your code the same, and copy the files you require from your project to the output directory. You can do that by simply setting the `Copy to Output Directory` setting to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Changing the path to go two folders up is a bad idea, since this won't be true in production scenarios, and will thus break your code.

Comment: I am not sure i understand , is there a method that will point me to this path?

var hardcodedPath= "C:\\Users\\Alan\\Desktop\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\TabControl\\xulrunner";

of course this part, C:\\Users\\Alan\\Desktop , is useless

Comment: No, why would you want to?

Answer (score 1):

To get exactly what you are looking for, you could do the following:

```
    var path2 = System.IO.Path.GetFullPath(System.IO.Path.Combine(Environment.CurrentDirectory, "..\\..\\xulrunner"));
```

However, please be aware that Environment.CurrentDirectory can change as your program runs. I have found that using the %PROGRAMDATA% environment variable works well for creating a location where you save data. It allows for a more consistent solution for using paths.

Additionally, the code snippet provided will only really be useful when you are running through the IDE's debugger. When you deploy, it will likely not give you what you are expecting.

It would help to know what is the overall functional result you are hoping for.